Python Error: Unable to create process using python Access is denied
Environment
I had python 3.11.x and 3.12.x installed. But I found that 3.11.x is more compatible with things in general, and 3.12.x isn't mainstream yet. Sorry if that badly described, but I think it's roughly correct.
Problem
In vscode, my code runs. I use a virtual environment.
But, I'm getting the following error:
vscode> py
Unable to create process using 
'"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.12.exe"': 
Access is denied.

What I've tried
Selected 3.11.x in palette, with Python: Select Interpreter.
Uninstalled 3.12, and ran 3.11 repair.
Uninstalled all versions of python, then re-installed 3.11.x.
Examined Windows environment variable in system properties, but don't see anything about python there.

Still getting same error.

Open the Python 3.12 installer and select Uninstall.


You can also use Python 3.11 to create a virtual environment in the workspace, select the virtual environment interpreter and then create a new terminal to activate the environment.
Also, you can just type python instead of py.

Thx, but as my question states, "Uninstalled all versions of python".

How do you uninstall? Reinstall python3.11 and on the install screen check the box py launcher.
https://imgur.com/xoMIIjS

I uninstall with the uninstaller. And I always use a virtual environment. My function runs fine. This post is only concerned with the error.

python instead of py was the fix! Did py replace python in 3.12? I recall reading something like that. Previously, i encountered  FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME in local.settings.json. But i completely uninstalled vscode, and purged all related directories, and reinstalled vscode since then. I see my local.settings.json has python for this setting.

As mentioned in my question, i do select 3.11 interpreter in the palette. My code runs. The only issue was the error at terminal.

I need to learn more about the pros & cons of py launcher. If possible, please talk about that in your answer.

Some Microsoft documentation uses py, so i need to understand why i need to use python. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages
